# playing sdcard video on textureview

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a video that I have on the sdcard of my device using Textureview, which according to the documentation, is the best solution to further transform the video, the problem is that when I put the path of an Internet video me working correctly , and when I put my route sdcard me the video is black, but the sound if it works, is very rare. I attached the code if you can help me, I've been searching like crazy but I find it can be happening, thanks in advance. regards

```
public class tres extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private MediaPlayer mp;
private TextureView textureview;

private String Path = "video.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tres);


textureview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.vista_video);
textureview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,
int height) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Surface s = new Surface(surface);

try {
mp= new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDir ectory()+"/" + Path);
mp.setSurface(s);
mp.prepare();

mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.start();


} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

im having exact the same issue.
current workarround is a running webserver app on the same device and setting the DataSource of my mediaPlayer instance to localhost.

but thats not the solution im hoping to find.